# Reverse Name order in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, string-manipulation

I have a load of names in a file in the format Lastname, Firstname:

> Williams, Hywel
>   Williams, Mark 
>   Williams, Roger
>   Williams, Stephen
>   ...

Is there a simple way of reversing them in Notepad++, to get each line reversed into Firstname Lastname like so?

> Hywel Williams
>   Mark Williams
>   Roger Williams
>   Stephen Williams
>   ...

Or any other simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "Replace" function with a regexp, replacing `^(.+), (.+)$` with `\2 \1`.